# get the data that was returned from the stored procedure SQL Server 2008 silvelight C# Linq

Tags: c#, silverlight, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

Hi everyone i just start to programe in Linq "Entity Framwork" with stored procedure and my probleme is :

i want to retrieve the data returned from the stored procedure here is my code :

here is my stored procedure it's just a simple select

```
USE [Arret_dev]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsTheSame] 
@ListeIdAffaires nvarchar(MAX),
AS
CREATE TABLE #AffairesIDs (AffaireID int);
DECLARE @requete nvarchar(max);
SELECT @requete =
    'INSERT INTO #AffairesIDs(AffaireID)
     SELECT [id] FROM [Affaire] WHERE ([id] in (' + @ListeIdAffaires + '))';
EXEC sp_executesql @requete;

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
RETURN SELECT *
FROM #AffairesIDs, [dbo].[Affaire]  
WHERE id = AffaireID ;
    END
DROP TABLE #AffairesIDs;
GO
```

the viewmodel code :

```
private void IsTheSame(){
    IsBusy = true;
    InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Affaire>> LoadAffaire = Context.Load(Context.IsTheSame(_selectedAffaires, InfoAffaire));
    LoadAffaire.Completed += new EventHandler(IsTheSame_Completed);
}

private void IsTheSame_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsBusy = false;
    TexteInfo = "Succès : les données des affaires sélectionnées ont été chargée.";
}
```

the DomaineService:

```
[Invoke]
public IEnumerable<Affaire> IsTheSame(IEnumerable<int> selectedAffaires, Affaire infoAffaire)
{
    // cette liste sera utilisée dans le IN de la proc stock
    string listeIdAffaires = string.Join(",", selectedAffaires.ToArray());

    return this.ObjectContext.IsTheSame(
        listeIdAffaires,
        );
}
```

if you need more information just ask me thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution :

```
    InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Affaire>> LoadAffaire;

    private void IsTheSame(){
        IsBusy = true;
        LoadAffaire = Context.IsTheSame(_selectedAffaires, InfoAffaire);
        LoadAffaire.Completed += new EventHandler(IsTheSame_Completed);
    }

    private void IsTheSame_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        TexteInfo = "Succès : les données des affaires sélectionnées ont été chargée.";
        IEnumerable<Affaire> affaire = LoadAffaire.Value.AsEnumerable();
        MessageBox.Show(affaire.ElementAt(0).nom_fichier_pretour);
    }
```

and for the stored procedure i take of the "RETURN".